# Call View.OnClickListener from Snackbar

Tags: android, kotlin, snackbar

I am trying to call ViewModel from my activity in a snackbar and since it requires a onClickListener it doesn't let me just do a simple

```
Snackbar.make(mViewBinding.root, "Note has been deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).apply {
    setAction("Undo", mViewModel.insertNote(event.data!!))
}
```

So the solution is to call with a View.OnClickListener but I found a weird solution that I'm trying to understand and I'd like to know if any of you could explain to me this.

```
Snackbar.make(mViewBinding.root, "Note has been deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).apply {
    setAction("Undo"){
        mViewModel.insertNote(event.data!!)
    }
}
```

**Question:** Why does setting a "**{**" works the same way? Is it an anonymous function?

Comment: Sorry are you sure both work? First would only work if whatever returned by insertNot implements interface OnClickListener. I very much doubt that's the case.

Comment: You should read a good article about Kotlin lambdas

Comment: This is called SAM conversion. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions

Comment: No the first doesn't work, the second yes. The first is what i did before getting into it. @ror

Comment: On my way! @Qunata

Comment: Thank you very much for providing me a link @Tenfour04 I'll take a look now!